# Android "do not ask me again" alert dialog box

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-alertdialog

guys! I'm trying to create a "do not ask me again" alert dialog pop-up box. But it is something wrong with my code. Check it out. What's wrong with it? It doesn't work, I think I put it in a wrong position. Could someone help me?

```
package com.example.exemplo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Listagem extends Activity
{

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile1"; 
public CheckBox dontShowAgain;


  private static class ViewHolder {
public TextView text;
public TextView text2;
public ImageView image;
}

 EditText edittext;
 ListView listview;

String[] text;

String[] text2;


int[] image = {
        R.drawable.wolf;
        R.drawable.cat;

    };

int textlength = 0;
ArrayList<String> text_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> text2_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> image_sort = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);


 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater adbInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View eulaLayout = adbInflater.inflate(R.layout.checkbox, null);
    dontShowAgain = (CheckBox) eulaLayout.findViewById(R.id.skip);
    adb.setView(eulaLayout);
    adb.setTitle("Attention");
    adb.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("How can I see this then?"));
    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String checkBoxResult = "NOT checked";
            if (dontShowAgain.isChecked())
                checkBoxResult = "checked";
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("skipMessage", checkBoxResult);
            // Commit the edits!
            editor.commit();
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://misha.beshkin.lv/android-alertdialog-with-checkbox/")));
            return;
        }
    });

    adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String checkBoxResult = "NOT checked";
            if (dontShowAgain.isChecked())
                checkBoxResult = "checked";
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("skipMessage", checkBoxResult);
            // Commit the edits!
            editor.commit();
            return;
        }
    });
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String skipMessage = settings.getString("skipMessage", "NOT checked");
    if (skipMessage != "checked")
        adb.show();

    super.onResume();
}
```

}

```
text =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.text);
text2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.text2);



edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);



listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
long arg3) {


    if ("Howl".equals(text[position])) {
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Listagem.this, R.raw.howl);
        player.start();


       }


    if ("Meow".equals(text[position])) {
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Listagem.this, R.raw.meow);
        player.start();            
}

        });






listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text, text2, image));

edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{

}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
int count, int after)
{

}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
int before, int count)
{

textlength = edittext.getText().length();
text_sort.clear();
text2_sort.clear();
image_sort.clear();

for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
{
if (textlength <= text[i].length())
{
if (edittext.getText().toString().
equalsIgnoreCase((String) text[i].subSequence(0, textlength)))
{
text_sort.add(text[i]);
text2_sort.add(text2[i]);
image_sort.add(image[i]);
}
}
}


listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
long arg3) {


    if ("Howl".equals(text_sort.get(position))) {
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Listagem.this, R.raw.howl);
        player.start();


       }


    if ("Meow".equals(text_sort.get(position))) {
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Listagem.this, R.raw.meow);
        player.start();


       }

}

        });

listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter
(text_sort, text2_sort, image_sort));

}


});
}



class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

String[] data_text;
String[] data_text2;
int[] data_image;

MyCustomAdapter()
{

}

MyCustomAdapter(String[] text, String[] text2, int[] image)
{
data_text = text;
data_text2 = text2;
data_image = image;
}
MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> text, ArrayList<String> text2, ArrayList<Integer>   image)
{
data_text = new String[text.size()];
data_text2 = new String[text2.size()];
data_image = new int[image.size()];

for(int i=0;i<text.size();i++)
{
data_text[i] = text.get(i);
data_text2[i] = text2.get(i);
data_image[i] = image.get(i);
}

}

public int getCount()
{
return data_text.length;

}

public String getItem(int position)
{
return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position)
{
return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

ViewHolder holder;


if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = getLayoutInflater();


    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);

    TextView textview2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "arial.ttf");  
    textview2.setTypeface(font1, Typeface.NORMAL);

    holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

}
holder.text.setText(data_text[position]);
holder.text2.setText(data_text2[position]);
holder.image.setImageResource(data_image[position]);






return convertView;
}





    }


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use == and != on strings

Use

```
if(!skipMessage.equals("checked"))
```

Instead of

```
if(skipMessage != "checked")
```

Comment: The problem is AlertBuilder, SharedPreferences, DialogInterface the eclipse says they cannot be resolved to a type :(

Comment: You will have to import them. Check the package and add import statement

Answer (score 1):

`==` compares your string refrences not sting value . you have to use `.equals()`

```
if (!skipMessage.equals("checked"))
        adb.show();
```